# Detect the file size of a link's href using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, iis

Would like to write a script to detect the file size of the target of a link on a web page.

Right now I have a function that finds all links to PDF files (i.e. the href ends with '.pdf') and appends the string '[pdf]' to the innerText. I would like to extend it so that I can also append some text advising the user that the target is a large file (e.g. greater than 1MB).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some web servers may give you a `Content-Length` header in response to a `HEAD` request. You could potentially use an XmlHttpRequest to send the `HEAD` request and see what you get.

Here's what one of my IIS servers says about a PDF file:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 127791
Content-Type: application/pdf
...
```

However, anything that's not delivered directly by the web server (a file served by PHP or ASP.net, for example) won't work unless the script specifically handles HEAD requests.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that might have been the way to go. The files are hosted by an IIS server that I control but the content is stored in a blob and is thus unstructured until rendered in the browser.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do a HEAD request using XMLHttpRequest, assuming the files are under the same domain.

This is however something that should really be done on the server side. Doing it with extra requests has no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: I agree that doing it server side would be ideal but unfortunately the content is stored as a blob in a DB. It doesn't have structure until rendered by the browser so any server side solution would involve running regexes on all the content even though I only care about a handful of links.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, or at least - not in any practical-cross-browser way.

If you know the filesize beforehand, for example when generating the document linking to the files you could hard-code the sizes into the HTML document.

```
<a href="large_file.pdf" onclick="return confirm('Want to download a large file?')">large_file.pdf</a>
```